# CoreVideo/CoreImage filter out background of video (substract two images)

Tags: ios, swift, video, filter, core-graphics

I'm using ijkplayer based on ffmpeg to play video in desired UIView.
Now I need to filter that UIView/Video. 
I want to achieve an effect similar to Mac PhotoBooth app and filter out the background. (assumming that camera is always static and the background is not changing) 
 Lets say, that the first frame of the video is only the background that I need to filter out.

 What is the most efficient way to do this? What filters should I use?